# How to store each web elements in a distinct variable whose index is increments in XPath for each web element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-structures

```
   String spath = ".//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[";

   String epath = "]/div[2]";
   for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

      String tpath = spath+i+epath;
      WebElement listpath = h.findElement(By.xpath(tpath));
      String list = listpath.getText();
      System.out.println(list);

    }
```

In this case I have stored all the **web elements** in the **single** variable "**list**", but I need to store **each web elements** in each **distinct** variable?

Comment: Please post a link to the page or the relevant HTML and a description of what the goal is.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you are going to access it later. If order is not important, create a set, which will also de-duplicate your elements, by adding on top:

```
Set<String> myElements = new HashSet<>();
```

If order is important, and you will need to access the elements in order, use:

```
List<String> myElements = new ListArray<>();
```

To add the elements in the collection you will use:

```
myElements.add(list);
```

Instead of printing it.

You can make your collection holding any type, for example you can replace String with WebElement. In that case add the listpath to your collection.